# git rm --cached file vs git reset file

Tags: git, git-reset, git-rm

I'm trying to learn Git. I'm confused between

```
git rm --cached file
```

and

```
git reset file
```

both of the commands seem to take the file from staged to un-staged area. How do the commands differ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between \`git rm --cached asd\` and \`git reset head -- asd\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798930/whats-the-difference-between-git-rm-cached-asd-and-git-reset-head-asd)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`git rm --cached <file>` will completely remove the file's contents from the index. This means that on commit the file will be removed from the `HEAD` commit. (If the file was only added to the index and not yet tracked this is a "no-op".)

`git reset -- <file>` resets the contents of the file in the index to be the same as the head commit. This means that on commit *no changes* will be committed to the file. This operation is not valid if there is no tracked version of the file in the `HEAD` commit.

Comment: Maybe as an addition: `git rm --cached` will add the *delete* action of the file to the index, just like `git add` will add an *add* action.

Comment: Is index==staging area? If a file is in the index, isn't it tracked by extension?

Comment: For git reset -- <file>, there should be a tracked version of that file in HEAD commit. If it's new file added to index, then there will be no tracked version in HEAD commit

Comment: So `git reset` doesn't reset the index to what it was right after the last commit, namely _empty_. It keeps the list of staged files, but resets their _contents_ to that of the last commit. Therefore, `git reset` isn't the opposite of (doesn't undo) `git add`.

Comment: is there a way to view files that are in the index? (even if they match the HEAD)

Comment: @bubaka I think you're looking for `git ls-files -s`. It lists all the files in the index, whether staged or not. What it shows will be what will be put in to your next commit.