# How to not track an added, uncommitted file in Git without using .gitignore

Tags: git, github

***Situation:*** I want to add a .rvmrc file in my git folder, but I realize that this file is unneeded across my entire team. I don't want to modify the .gitignore file just for my own needs sake. However, I am unskilled in this area of git, so any advice in the answer column is appreciated

Therefore, I was looking around the web for a command or git concept about ignoring a file added to a git repo. Every article I look at either points me to adding something into the .gitignore (which I don't want to because it'll cause a new commit) or ignoring files locally that are already tracked. Could someone give me a pointer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for Git's `.git/info/exclude` file.

This file is meant for "private ignores", similar to `.gitignore` but only for one copy of the repository. They are *not* committed to the repository.

Here is what [GitHub has to say about the matter](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files#explicit-repository-excludes):

> ### Explicit repository excludes
>
> If you don't want to create a `.gitignore` file to share with others, you can create rules that **are not committed** with the repository. You can use this technique for locally-generated files that you don't expect other users to generate, such as files created by your editor.
>
> Use your favorite text editor to open the file called `.git/info/exclude` within the root of your Git repository. Any rule you add here will not be checked in, and will only ingore files for your local repository.
>
> 1. In Terminal, navigate to the location of your Git repository.
> 2. Using your favorite text editor, open the file `.git/info/exclude`.

Comment: Do I just add the name to that file?

Comment: @ForgetfulFellow, you can use the same types of patterns that are supported by `.gitignore`. Adding `.rvmrc` to the file should work, but it will also ignore any `.rvmrc` files in subdirectories of the repository.

Answer (score 1):

What's your purpose?
If need to remove a file you added (and not yet committed) by mistake, just do

```
git reset <path_to_unadd>
```

which will simply move the file from the staging area to the working copy.

Otherwise I see no reasons for not using a .gitignore, which is a different concept.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply looking to remove a file from the staging area (added but not committed), use [git rm](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html).

Specifically, if you want to remove a file from the staging area but not have it removed from the working tree, use `git rm --cached file.ext`

If you want to permanently ignore a file, use a `.gitignore`, I don't see any issues with adding an extra commit for that, it prevents other contributors from adding and committing the files you want to ignore.

Comment: `git rm`? Why not just a `git reset`?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella `git reset` isn't considered valid if the added file is a new file. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12661306/1122135

Comment: works for me, that answer is probably referring to an old version of git.