# How to remove "too large" file from git history?

Tags: git, github

I added a 212MB file to my folder and committed it and tried to push it. Git told me that the file size was too big so I can't push it. I deleted the file, but it is still shown when I try to push my code.

My actual steps were:

1. I did `git add .`
2. Then `git commit -m "New css"`
3. Then `git push origin development`
4. Then it took a long time to run the above command. It ended with saying "path/to/file/file.mp4 is 212MB which is too big. Failed to push".
5. Then I deleted that file manually.
6. Tried pushing again, same problem.

I was told by other stackoverflow answers to use `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf path/to/your/file' HEAD`

I'm just trying to understand what this means. Will this affect my whole repo or just the above mentioned file? What happens if I manually deleted the file already? So the file path doesn't exist.

For example, since I tried pushing to the development branch, I did `git push origin development`. This failed, so assuming the file I'm trying to delete is named Testing.mp4, should this be the code:

`git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf public/uploads/videos/testing.mp4' HEAD`

Am I right? Again, this will ONLY delete the video and nothing else?

Comment: How did you delete the file? `rm`? did you run `git rm`?

Comment: @bencripps no, I went back on my website locally and clicked on "delete", then I checked the folder, it was no there anymore. Did not delete through git

Comment: you can run git rm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting the file from filesystem won't necessary mean removing it from git if it was previously added to the index (`git add path/to/file`), but just record a delete operation.

Depending on what you did previously, git may be trying to push your various actions in order: add the file first (which fail due to file size) then delete it.

To actually stop tracking this file you could try to remove it from index: `git rm --cached path/to/file`

Remember later to always `git rm` a problematic file rather than simply deleting it, `git rm` will delete the file AND remove it from index at the same time.

A good expanation from manojlds lies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798930/git-rm-cached-x-vs-git-reset-head-x)

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. I updated my question. Should I still do "git rm --public/uploads/videos/testing.mp4"?

Comment: @LizzyTheLearner probably should still do `git rm --cached /path/to/file`

Comment: According to your actions, "git rm" and "git rm --cached" should have the same effect, git rm won't complain if the file is not found. But since you committed the whole thing, the delete operation will still occur ...

Comment: @Eddie It gives me the following error "fatal: pathspec path/to/file did not match any files". I tried both git rm and git rm --cached :(

Comment: What is the output of "git ls-files", do you still see your file appearing ?

Comment: By the way, another way to "come back" would be to reset your repository to a working commit since the push failed, ie for the previous commit : git reset --hard head~1 (make a copy of your files first just in case ;))

Comment: @LizzyTheLearner why not check `git status` and see where your deleted file go? if it's in the removed section, then you might want do another `git add .` `git commit -am "delete large file"`

Comment: @Eddie and Antoine, thanks guys. I did git filter branch and it worked

Comment: Glad you could save your repository ! You should maybe edit your question to include the working solution since my answer was not relevant in your situation :/

Answer (score 0):

your project contain files with size larger than 100MB, you can remove these large files using [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) before putting to github.

There is a tutorial about [How to solve Github import error: "We found an error during import"](https://cloudreports.net/how-to-solve-github-import-error-we-found-error-during-import/). Remember to backup your project source code and git database.

Dowload BFG, clone your repository with `--mirror` flag and just run:

```
java -jar bfg-1.13.0.jar --no-blob-protection --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M your-repo.git

cd your-repo.git
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git push
```

Comment: does not work with gitlab and ssh://git@mygitlab.com:20033/mynamespace/my-repo.git