# failed to push into github - large file

Tags: github, github-actions

I tried pushing files into my github repo and a file sized big and indeed i removed that file from my git status. But that file still causes size issues.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Obviously Github has a file limit 100Mb. Please see here:
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/conditions-for-large-files
And here they suggest how to work with large files:
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/versioning-large-files

Also, on the error you get. It suggest you to use LFS

Comment: The error message should be posted as text. & There's not enough information to debug the issue. Do you have the file in the git commit log (history)?

Comment: How do i remove and re-solve the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135185/how-to-remove-too-large-file-from-git-history

Comment: Yeah did see that post, But couldn't help. I used *git rm --cached myfile.json*.. Once, I looked into git status it shows myfile.json was untracked. But after the push it still shows the same error as in the screenshot